# How to Customize Xamarin Forms ListView SelectedItem ViewCell Visibility?

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms XAML, I want to hide part of ViewCell if it is not selected.
For example the second label with text="Show only if selected".
How to do that using MVVM without code behind?

`<ListView x:Name="listView">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
                 <StackLayout>
                     <Label Text="Always Show it"/>
                     <Label Text="Show only if selected" IsVisible={Binding somewhere?}/>
                 </StackLayout>
             </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible MVVM approach, which involve no code-behind.

**ViewModels**

Add a property* in your `ListView` item viewmodel to store information that indicate whether the item is currently selected :

```cs
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ......

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if(_selectedItem != value)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the page's viewmodel, have another property* for binding `ListView`'s `SelectedItem`, in the setter of which you can setup `IsSelected` value accordingly :

```cs
private ItemViewModel _selectedItem;
public ItemViewModel SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if(_selectedItem != value)
        {
            //update previously selected item, if any :
            if(_selectedItem != null) _selectedItem.IsSelected = false;

            //update currently selected item :
            value.IsSelected = true;

            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

Bind `IsVisible` property to the `ListView` item viewmodel :

```
<Label Text="Show only if selected" IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
```

---

*) The property needs to be a public property, in a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` or inherits other class that implements it, **and** the property raises property-changed notification accordingly, as exemplified in the above snippets.

---

For reference:

- Xamarin official guide: [Part 5. From Data Bindings to MVVM](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/)
- Complete example of the above codes in [Gist](https://gist.github.com/har07/dd80c8316a08d48ea1f22e733339b7fc)

Answer (score 0):

Each item in your listview needs to have a "IsSelected" bindable property. Then on your listviews ItemSelected event get the item and set is IsSelected to true. Just make sure you keep a reference the the currently selected item so that you can set the IsSelected to false on it one a new selected item is pressed. It should look something like this.

```
    MyItem _currentlySelectedItem;
    void OnSelection (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.SelectedItem == null) {
        _currentlySelectedItem = null;
        return; //ItemSelected is called on deselection, which results in SelectedItem being set to null
      }
      var selectedItem = e.SelectedItem as MyItem;
      selectedItem .IsSelected= true;
     _currentlySelectedItem.IsSelected= false; /// Make sure to check for null
     _currentlySelectedItem = selectedItem ;
    }
```

Comment: Is Bindable Property like AttachedProperty in WPF?

Comment: @YohanesNurcahyo Not sure since I don't use WPF. You might want to read https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/ to understand how bindings work.

Comment: There are many method to create BindableProperty, which is should I used?
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty/